# Update only clicked image on GridView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, custom-adapter

I have a GridView using a custom adapter for ImageView elements. I want to change ImageView onItemClick and I have some conditions for clicking. If the clicked item is available i change the image. But when I change the image resource for item i have to update whole GridView by adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();. My GridView has 100 elements so updating them all costs me half a second delay and it's disturbing. How can i update only the elements that i have changed ?

Here is my getView() method in adapter.

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Point point;
    View v = null;
    point=items.get(position); 
    int resId;
    resId=point.getBackground();
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    ImageView tv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_button);
    tv.setImageResource(resId);
    return v;
}
```

Here is my getBackground() method on Point object

```
public int getBackground(){
    int backId=(R.drawable.button_initial);
    if(isFilled){
        backId=(R.drawable.button_clicked);
    }
    else if(isAvailable){
        backId=(R.drawable.button_green);
    }
    return backId;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW: `ackId=(R.drawable.button_clicked)` what are there brackets for?

Comment: Bad old habits. I use brackets for everything i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You should update the point in the items list and then call     notifyDataSetChanged();

It is best if you do that in the Activity..like that

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayLIst<Point>;
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(points);

    gridView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Point p = items.get(position);
        p.setBackground(..);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      @Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

      }
    });
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing actually. I set values in Activity and call the  notifyDataSetChanged();. But when i call the method it updates whole GridView and cause a delay. So i don't want to use  notifyDataSetChanged(); that's the problem

Comment: It is not the recommended way but you could  put a clicklistener on a view when you inflate it.

v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

You should also consider using the ViewHolder pattern.